# Use an Anonymous object in HtmlHelper extension method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, anonymous-class

I would like to extend the [HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), in order to render script tags with custom attributes ('async', by example)

I would like to use it like this

```
@Html.RenderBundleScript("/mybundleName", new { async = ""})
```

this is my code, that does not work (specially, `attributes.ToString()` gives: *`System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary`* instead of *`async`* or *`async=''`*):

```
public static IHtmlString RenderBundleScript(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                               string bundlePath, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    string attributesValue = (attributes == null) ? 
                             string.Empty : attributes.ToString();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(attributesValue))
    {
        return Scripts.Render(bundlePath);
    }
    else
    {
        //var tag = new TagBuilder("script");
        // tag.MergeAttribute() ???
        return Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' " + 
                       attributesValue + 
                       " type='text/javascript'></script>", bundlePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can define "does not work" a bit better? Do you get any output or exceptions? If so, what?

Comment: I don't arrive to convert the anonymous object {async=""} to a list of html attributes ("`async=''`").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scripts class has a method [`Scripts.RenderFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.scripts.renderformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accepts a format string, which would be used to render each of the scripts in the bundle.

This could come handy for your extension method. You could use the html attributes to create a format string for the script tags. This format string would look like this:

```
 <script async="" fooAttrib="1" src="{0}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So you can update the extension method by implementing this idea as:

```
public static IHtmlString RenderBundleScript(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                        string bundlePath, object htmlAttributes)
{
    if (htmlAttributes == null)
    {
        return Scripts.Render(bundlePath);
    }
    else
    {            
        //Create format string for the script tags, including additional html attributes    
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("script");
        tag.Attributes.Add("src", "{0}");
        tag.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
        var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        foreach (var key in attributes.Keys)
        {
            tag.Attributes.Add(key, attributes[key].ToString());
        }                
        var tagFormat = tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        //render the scripts in the bundle using the custom format
        return Scripts.RenderFormat(tagFormat, bundlePath);
    }
}
```

If you call it as in the following line:

```
@Html.RenderBundleScript("~/bundles/jqueryval", new {async = "", dummy="1"})
```

It will render this output:

```
<script async="" dummy="1" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script async="" dummy="1" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This work pretty well... the only bemol is that there is no (?) possiblility to add valueless attributes, like just "async"...

Comment: Good point! However an empty value (or a value equals to the attribute name like `async="async"`) would be valid according to the W3C [html5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/semantics.html#boolean0): _If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is a case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace_. If you still want that, you might need to manually build the tagFormat string instead of using the `TagBuilder` class.